# Can you dynamically add local variables to a function?

Tags: javascript

I'm using objects to namespace my JavaScript code. These objects usually contain functions that are called mapping the `this`-pointer to the object itself using `apply`. However, I find it inconvenient to use the `this`-pointer everytime I want to access other functions or properties of the object, especially because in lots of cases I use the `new`-operator to use function-objects the way you would use classes. I would prefer writing `new Line()` instead if `new this.Line()`.

It would be great if you could add local variables to a function the way php does it with `extract` (pseudocode following, it's a little more complicated)

```
var sample_object = {
  "some_function": function() {}
}

test() {
  extract(sample_object);
  some_function();   // imported from sample_object
}
```

Is that even possible?

Comment: You *could* use a `with` block, but, I don't suggest it.  I also think it's removed in ES5 strict mode.

Comment: @Rocket I'd uparrow the not suggesting it part if I could :-) It's true it'd work, but `with` is confusing and weird. Also I'm pretty sure it causes performance problems but I can't remember the explanation for that.

Comment: What if you pass an array as argument?

Comment: @elvenbyte: How would that help?

Comment: @Rocket has the answer. `with` is what you want, though, it _is_ forbidden from ES5 strict mode, and as @Pointy remarks, it does have performance problems: "`with` forces the specified object to be searched first for all name lookups. Therefore all identifiers that aren't members of the specified object will be found more slowly in a 'with' block. Where performance is important, 'with' should only be used to encompass code blocks that access members of the specified object." (MDN) Other than using `with`, there's no other way I know of.

Comment: You *could* also loop through the object and use `eval` to create variables with the names of the keys, but I don't suggest this either.

Comment: Objects being subject to prototype inheritance makes lookup on them (inside `with`-blocks) even more expensive.

Comment: @elvenbyte, since valid variable identifiers can't start with a numeric character, you'll only be able to access members of such an array via `slice`.

Comment: you can create an array and every item could be an argument.

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure `eval` is your only answer; but you need to be aware that if there's any input outside of your control involved, it isn't safe

```
function dynamicArgs (varName, varValue) {
  eval("var " + varName + "=" + JSON.encode(varValue) );
  alert(a);
}

dynamicArgs("a", "value");
```

You can see the problem with this. How is your function supposed to call the dynamic variable if it doesn't know its name? I hardcoded it to the a variable since I pass it in when calling it, but that's not a good solution. The only solution would be another `eval`. You really should think about what you need to do and whether this is useful. But it's doable.

Here it is in action: http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/GG3Wu/

```
function dynamicArgs (varName, varValue) {
  eval('var ' + varName + "='" + varValue + "';");
  alert(eval(varName));
}

dynamicArgs("f", "Here I am");
```

Now here's an example like what you're doing, creating a variable from `this.MyConstructor` 
http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/AK3WD/

```
var ns = {
    MyConstructor: function(val) {
       this.prop = val;
    },

    runConstructor: function(val) {
      var Ctor = "MyConstructor";
      eval('var ' + Ctor + ' =  this.' + Ctor);
      return new MyConstructor(val);
    }
}


alert( ns.runConstructor("Hello").prop );
```

And here's an example if you wanted to import all the values from an object into the scope;

http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/AK3WD/1/

```
var ns = {
    MyConstructor: function(val) {
       this.val= val;
    },

    anotherProperty: 5,

    runConstructor: function(val) {
        // Bring all the variables from this into this scope
        for (var prop in this) {
            eval('var ' + prop + ' =  this.' + prop);
        }
        alert('Testing var anotherProperty: ' + anotherProperty);
        var obj =  new MyConstructor(val);
        alert('Created MyConstructor: its prop is ' + obj.val)
    }
}


ns.runConstructor("Hello");
```

Answer (score 3):

There is controversial [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with), which has some [great applications](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/), but is marginally slow and prone to errors. It throws an error in the strict mode (which you should always opt into) and is going to be deprecated.

```
var sampleObject = {
  someFunction: function() {},
  b: 10
}

with (sampleObject) {
    typeof someFunction // "function"

    var a = 42
    var b = 20
}

sampleObject.a // undefined
sampleObject.b // 20
```

Note, that new variables defined in a `with`-block won't be added to the object. Nevertheless, if the object already had an eponymous property in it, this property would be modified (thanks, @Rocket).

*Just for fun*, here's [an implementation of `extract`](http://jsfiddle.net/vTbnM/) using [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) (which is even more evil than `with`). You can do unspeakable things with it, for example if your object has properties like `sampleObject['x; while (true) { alert("Hi!") }']`.

Comment: You can't add variables to an object in `with`, but you can modify them.  Check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/HkEVW/

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it:

```
   function smObject ( object) {
    return function () {
        function getter(prop) {
            return function() {
                return this[prop];
            }
        }

        function setter(prop) {
            return function(data) {
                this[prop]=data;
            }
        }

        for (var o = 0; o < object.length; o++) {
            this[object[o]] = {};
            this['get' + object[o]] = getter(object[o]);
            this['set' + object[o]] = setter(object[o]);
        }
    }
}
```

now you can instantiate a function like this:

```
var fields = ['Name', 'Id', 'Other', '....' ]
var MyFunction = smObject( fields );
var myObject = new MyFunction();

// getter/setters
myObject.setId(5);
myObject.getId(); // will return 5
```

Regards,
Emanouil